# how do I make windows service complete all code before repeating process

Tags: c#, .net, service

So I created a service to run on a server and look at different folder shares and put them in a database table for a customized search but it pulls a datatable of search locations in and iterates through them one at a time which worked great with small test folders. Now that I tried to use it for real it does not make it through the first folder path before my timer restarts it. I could make it time longer but I basically want this to run constantly and start over as soon as the first one is done or not sure if I can run all paths at the same time. I had it running every 30 Minutes but definitely not long enough.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;


namespace MFTSearchService
{
    public partial class MFTSearchService : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(); // name space(using System.Timers;)
        public MFTSearchService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds; //number in milisecinds  
            timer.Enabled = true;
            //global::MFTSearchService.Search.SearchStart();


        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is recall at " + DateTime.Now);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).TotalMilliseconds; //number in milisecinds  
            timer.Enabled = true;
            global::MFTSearchService.Search.SearchStart();

        }
        public void WriteToFile(string Message)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\ServiceLog_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.   
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than using a polling design, why not just have the service schedule itself again -after- its done, i.e. a recursive design?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling

```
global::MFTSearchService.Search.SearchStart();
```

in your timer, you can add a BackgroundWorker and start it in your timer. For every tick on your timer, you can check if Backgroundworker is busy or not. BackgroundWorker will not run until it's done if you check it before running it.

```
private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    WriteToFile("Service is recall at " + DateTime.Now);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).TotalMilliseconds; //number in milisecinds  
    timer.Enabled = true;
    if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy())
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    global::MFTSearchService.Search.SearchStart();
}
```

Background worker will not lock your main thread so your timer will continue looping. So you're free to put any interval to it.

Comment: I tried this just kept giving me errors. It didn't like either of the  backgroundWorker1